# Get data from a JSON multi-level

Tags: php, json, export

I have searched and read a lot of different forums to manage JSON data
i have tried many things, but none of them works ;(

```
{"data": {"results": [{"qid_data": {"custom_id": "XXXXXX", "labels": "YYYYY", "meta": "{}", "bbox": [73, 57, 128, 516], "obj_id": "ZZZZZZ"}, "qid": "WWWWWWWW"}], "error": 0}}
```

I would like to get the values of:
`custom_id`, `labels`, `bbox`, `objet_id`, `qid`

Right now I have the following code (for example for `custom_id`)

```
$json_output = json_decode($data);
foreach ($json_output as $json_result) {
echo "custom_id:".$json_result->data->results->qid_data->custom_id;
}
```

I have tried all the variations possible.

`$json_result->results->qid_data->custom_id;`

OR

`$json_result->results->qid_data->custom_id;`

OR

`$json_result->data->results->custom_id;`

OR

`$json_result->results->custom_id;`

I never get the result, always an error

If someone can help on how to export with an example for
data `custom_id`, `bbox`, `qid`

Comment: I appreciate the winky emoticons, I really do, but I don't know if they really have a place in this post

Comment: What is the error and what does `print_r($json_output);` return?

Answer (score 3):

```
{"data": {"results": [{"qid_data": {"
```

does not equal

```
$json_result->results->qid_data
```

it equals

```
 $json_output->data->results[0]->qid_data
```

notice the square bracket showing results is a list

```
{"data": {"results": [{"qid_data": {"
                     ^
```

It looks like what you want is to iterate that list

```
foreach ($json_output->data->results as $result) {
    echo "custom_id:".$result->qid_data->custom_id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and explaination
I understand now what was the mistake, and i get all the data i want
thanks!